# Smooth Div Scroll Manuel Scrolling Option

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, smoothing

I am using the jquery plugin smooth-div-scroll from Thomas Kahn and I really like it. I have set the manualContinuousScrolling option "true" but endless manuel scroll in i big loop works only left and not left and right. Documentation says it should work left and right. Here is my test site: http://test.somersetheights.co.za/unser_haus.html.

Any idea why it is not scrolling endless in both directions? Thanks for your help.

Regards,

Peter

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer comes really late and I guess that's why the test site is not online anymore(?)

On [smoothdivscroll.com](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com) there are examples with continuous manual scrolling that works in both directions so I'm thinking you've missed something in your code? Since you asked this question the plugin has been updated to version 1.3. Perhaps you could check if the update solves your problem?